# making a simple zero phase butterworth filter?

Tags: matlab, filtering

I'm trying to make two zero phase filters with butterworth for a research project on matlab with a 1000hz low pass and a 5hz high pass, but I'm having trouble doing it because I've just started using it. So far I'm just trying youtube tutorials and slightly modifying their code, but I don't know where to put the frequency value. Could anyone help me out with writing a script?

```
x = audioread('audio file goes here.wav');
pressure1_seg = x(44100*20 : 44100*50);
d1 = designfilt('lowpassiir','FilterOrder',2, ...
    'HalfPowerFrequency',0.15,'DesignMethod','butter');
y = filtfilt(d1,pressure1_seg);
d2 = designfilt('highpassiir', 'FilterOrder',2, ...
    'HalfPowerFrequency',0.15,'DesignMethod','butter');
y1 = filtfilt(d2,y);
subplot(1,1,1)
plot(pressure1_seg)
hold on
plot(y,'LineWidth',3)
legend('Noisy ECG','Zero-Phase Filtering')
```

Comment: Do you have the signal processing toolbox? You could just use `butter` if you do.

Comment: Your frequency is the 0.15 in your `designfilt` function, it stands for 0.15 pi radians /s also known as the normalized frequency, so you can modify the code by converting your frequency (you better know your sampling frequency).

Comment: Thanks! Yea it's 44.1khz so I would just convert it with 1/44100 * 2 * pi * my desired cutoff frequency to get my desired cutoff frequencies in rads/sample right?